# assigning struct in switch not working

Tags: c

In my program, I'm trying to create a new struct based od switch statement, but when I do so, the compiler returns an error:

`Syntax error before '{' token` on the row with the position assignment

I'm using dev-c++ 4.9.9.2 as an IDE (i think it's using MinGW as compiler). IT's for my brother's programming assignment I'm helping him with, I haven't seen C in a few years, so I'm rusty (and I wasn't a champion before either).

Here's simplified code:

```
typedef enum{TOP_RIGHT = 0,TOP_LEFT,BOTTOM_RIGHT,BOTTOM_LEFT} diagonal_t;
typedef struct
{
   int row;
   int column;
} position_t;
...
void checkDiagonal(diagonal_t diagonal_to_check)
{
    ...
    position_t position;
    switch(diagonal_to_check)
    {
        case TOP_RIGHT:
             position = {0,0}; //here's the error, but I don't know how to repair it.
                               //how to create a new struct here without disrupting the
                               //switch?
             break;
        case TOP_LEFT:
             position = {0,0};
             break;
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: `position = (position_t){0,0};` in C99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var_of_type_struct = { init_value }` syntax works only in definitions; it does not work in assignments.

Three common ways to deal with is are

1. Defining a function that initializes your `struct`
2. Defining a function that sets fields to parameters that you pass, and
3. Assigning the individual fields of your `struct`.

Approach 1:

```
void init_pos(position_t *p) {
    p->row = 0;
    p->column = 0;
}
...
case TOP_LEFT:
    init_pos(&position);
    break;
```

Approach 2:

```
void set_pos(position_t *p, int r, int c) {
    p->row = r;
    p->column = c;
}
...
case TOP_LEFT:
    set_pos(&position, 0, 0);
    break;
```

Approach 3:

```
case TOP_LEFT:
    position.row = 0;
    position.column = 0;
    break;
```

Comment: @harper Yes, you're right! Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that: assignment and initialization are not the same thing. You are attempting to use initializer syntax in an assignment. You'll have to set both fields manually:

```
case TOP_RIGHT:
         position.row = 0;
         position.column = 0;
/* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to struct type, like this:

```
position = (position_t){0, 0};
```